# System-wise Agda input

Tags: notation, agda-mode, input-method

[Agda input](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/data/emacs-mode/agda-input.el) is an input method for Emacs that allows one to write `\bV` and have the unicode  inserted instead. This makes writing mathematical symbols more comfortable than it would be with the usual `Ctrl+Shift+U+(unicode point)`, if only because it is much easier to memorize and find `\bV` than `1D54D`. The mode comes with suggested autocompletions as well.

Can this input method be repeated system-wise instead of only inside emacs? Is there any already available software doing this?

Comment: I think that a nicely configured `.Xcompose` might be what I was looking for.